# Python: tkinter, adding entry to listbox doesn't response

Tags: python, user-interface, python-3.x, tkinter

For some reason, it doesn't add the element to the listbox. I guess it's because of the program order, but i'm not sure how should I properly put the code in the right order

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.grid()

        self.lb = Listbox()
        self.lb.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=5, rowspan=4,padx=5,sticky=E+W+S+N)

        self.e = Entry()
        self.e.grid( column=0, row=0, padx=5)
        self.badd = Button(text="Add", command=self.addtolistbox())
        self.badd.grid( column=1, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)
        self.brmv = Button(text="Remove")
        self.brmv.grid(column=2, row=0, padx=5, pady=5)

    def addtolistbox(self):
        self.lb.insert(0, self.e.get())


App = App(Tk())
App.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line

```
self.badd = Button(text="Add", command=self.addtolistbox())
```

to this

```
self.badd = Button(text="Add", command=self.addtolistbox)
```

The problem is that instead of binding the callback function to the button, you *execute* the function once (adding an empty string to the list) and then bind the result of the function call to the button, i.e. `None`.